# Transitive closure and invertible function

Tags: functions, relations

I have some questions as follow...

1) How could I prove transitive closure $t(R)=R^+$, where $R^+=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}R^k$, $R\subseteq A\times A$?

2) Prove or disprove: For any subset $A'\subseteq A,$ we always have $A' \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A'))$?

Comment: Start by writing down the definitions of transitive closure, and of $f^{-1}(f(A'))$, and try to work from there.  (This sounds like pretty obvious advice, but it's surprising how often people don't even do that before deciding they don't know how to approach a problem.)

Comment: Thanks! I take your advice and prove it.

Comment: What are you stuck on with the first one?  Do you know the definition of transitive closure and of $R^k$?

Answer (score 0):

Although I still have no idea of how to prove the first question,

I try to prove the second one with the advice from @Tara B

Here's how I prove it..

(1) Write down the definition:

$$
\because \forall x \in A' 
\\\rightarrow f(x) = y \in B
\\\rightarrow A'\subseteq B
\\\rightarrow f^{-1}(f(A)) = \left \{ a \in A | f(a) \in f(A') \right \} 
$$

(2) Then prove it:
$$
\forall x \in A' 
\\\rightarrow f(x) \in f(A')
\\\rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(f(A'))
\\\rightarrow A' \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A'))
$$

Comment: I think you have understood it, although your way of writing maths isn't completely intelligible to me.  What do you mean by $\rightarrow$?  My first guess would be 'implies', but then the beginning of the proof would be 'For all $x$ in $A'$ implies $\ldots$', which doesn't make sense.

Comment: So how should I prove it intelligibly? I don't have any idea with the structure or steps while proving this kind of question.

Comment: I added my way of writing it underneath your answer.  The edit hasn't come through yet though, so I don't know whether it will be accepted.  In general I would suggest writing a few words in your proofs rather than using only symbols.  Try reading aloud what you have written to check whether it makes sense.

Comment: Well, my edit was rejected, because people thought it should be an answer rather than a comment.  I didn't really want to put it as a separate answer, but I guess I will when I get time.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to write down some description after writing down the definition.